# Vertical Page breaks in html

Tags: html, css

Let's say I  have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col A</th>
          <th>Col B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Page 1</td>
          <td>Page 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The objective is that the column with header Col A , and all it's contents, appears in the first page and column Col B , and all it's contents, appears in the second page

So far, what I've tried 4 different ways with no success:

```
  <style type = "text/css">
     th {page-break-after: always;}
     th {page-break-after: left;}
     td {page-break-after: always;}
     td {page-break-after: left;}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the nuclear option, instead of one table with two columns, I made two tables with one column and used the page break

```
  <style type = "text/css">
     table {page-break-after: always;}
  </style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col A</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Page 1</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Page 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It isn't the most elegant solution, but it worked